# How to get image src value from server side jquery datatable in datatable?

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable and filling that datatable with ajax call and its working fine but now i need to shows the images in a column but i m don't know how to bind these images.Image link is coming from backend in category_image.

**Back End:**

```
var displayedCategories = filteredCategories;
var result = from c in displayedCategories select new[] 
{c.id, c.category_name, c.category_image,c.id};
return Json(new{
sEcho = param.sEcho,
iTotalRecords = lstAllCategories.Count,
iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
aaData = result},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Front End:**

```
$('#tblInterests').dataTable({
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
"bProcessing": true,
"bLengthChange": false,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bSort": true,
"aoColumns":[
{"sName": "id"},
{"sName": "category_name" },
{"sName": "category_image",
"bSearchable": false,
"bSortable": false,
"mRender": function (data) {
return '<img src="" width="50" height="50" />'
}
},
{"mData": "Id",
"bSearchable": false,
"bSortable": false,
"sWidth": "40px",
"mRender": function (data) {
return '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >Edit</button>'
}
},
],
"ajax": "/Admin/InterestsJson",
"columns": [
{ "data": "id" },
{ "data": "category_name" },
{ "data": "category_image" },
{ "data": "id" }
]
});
```

Comment: you forget to actually use the image -> `return '<img src="'+data+'" width="50" height="50" />' `

Comment: thanku so much davidkonrad..... give it in answer so i can accept and vote up u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `mRender`, `data` (==`category_image`) should be set as `src` for the image :

```
...
{ "sName": "category_image",
  "bSearchable": false,
  "bSortable": false,
  "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
     return '<img src="'+data+'" width="50" height="50" />'
  }
}
...
```

Comment: what is type and full in this

Comment: @Manjitsingh Thank you for accepting the answer! I just gave the full param list, if any one should be curious. It does not make difference for you. `type` is the render type - it can be `filter`, `display`, `type` or `sort`. It gives the possibility to return one result when the column is sorted, another when you are filtering, a third for displaying and so on.  `full` is all data for the current row / record, can be used if you want to combine multiple values from the record into one column.